# How can I clear a clogged drain vent without going on the roof?

Tags: roof, drain-waste-vent, clog, cleanout

I seem to have the classic problem of a clogged vent; flush toilet and shower drain "gasps".

Is there a good alternative to going up on the roof and clearing it from there? What's the recommended tool, if the problem isn't just a bird's nest -- standard drain auger from the top?

(I've climbed lots of roofs in my time, but I'm getting just old enough that I may want someone else to deal with that.)

Folks have asked about availability of clean-out T's. I don't think there's currently one that will let me hit this vent. I do have attic access, so could presumably splice something into the PVC there to reduce climbing in the future; doing it without disturbing whatever seals the roof penetration might be tricky, though.

Comment: Understood. But if I _am_ willing... Standard auger I'd use for a sink drain,, or something else?

Comment: A hose has worked for me.  However it would take 2 people logically if you didn't want to risk getting wet.  A drain auger can work too.  I had a neighbor that cleared a vent stack with a hockey stick... but that was just luck.

Comment: Avoiding the roof climb depends what you have (or add) for internal clean-out access.

Comment: Good answers depend on the situation--what's available for cleanouts and other entry points, roof height and access, etc. Please revise with more information about yours. Otherwise you'll get, at best, a list of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the pipe in your attic or basement then consider getting a sanitary tee installed or a long-sweep wye with a screw cap. When clogged then insert an auger upwards and knock out the clog.

Comment: Great idea. A pinch of prevention...